# NVIDIA 173 drivers/nvidia-settings are never loaded on boot

Tags: 10.04, xorg, nvidia, login-screen

It seems while the 173 driver is installed, my resolution settings are not loaded when I log in or reboot. I've tried opening nvidia-settings as superuser and user, changed the resolution, applied, then saved it to the default xorg conf file (while giving my password when needed.). Nothing I do seems to fix this issue.

If anyone could help, that'd be great.

(Running the equivelant of Ubuntu 10.04 I think, when I'm actually on Mint. (Kernel 2.6.32-24-generic #42-ubuntu)

xorg.conf file:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 1.0  (buildd@palmer)  Fri Apr  9 10:35:18 UTC 2010

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL D1028L"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 69.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 120.0
        Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce FX 5500"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1024x768 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka!

It seems to be fixed after the recent kernel update, 2.6.32-25. After applying that update and rebooting, NVIDIA kept crashing gdm, and I was given several options. I chose the option of creating a new (default) xorg.conf file.
I did so and rebooted, and suddenly, everything works fine! Even the resolution not sticking has been fixed!

Thank you Ubuntu developers, and you especially Ralf, for helping me along here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly save them.

Try running nvidia-settings with root privileges:

```
gksu nvidia-settings
```

Then go to "X-Server Display Configuration", setup your resolution and possibly meta-modes and click "Save to X Configuration File"

Close Nvidia-settings. They are now saved.

Comment: I guess I'm confused by your instructions. Am I supposed to set my resolution somewhere other than the X Server Display Configuration tab? That's where I've always been doing it, and by the chronology of your instructions, it seems that the resolution should be set elsewhere.

Comment: @TGP1994 You are right, I formulated my instructions in a confusion manner. The point was, you need to save the settings to your xorg.conf and you can only do that as root.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, that's one of the many things I've tried already :( Any other ideas? (If you wouldn't mind supporting it as a bug report, I've created it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-settings/+bug/634648)

Comment: Hmm. That works here and you don't mention actually clicking on the 'save to X configuration file' button. And you also don't mention if you launched it usin gksu or not. I've mentioned intentionally. You need to be root to overwrite your xorg.conf

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's why it prompts you for a password when you go to save the configuration file, right? To get root privileges to overwrite the file? And when I said saved to /etc/X11/xorg.conf, that would imply that I've clicked the save to X configuration file button :)

Comment: Ohw, that would be new thing. It just gave an error in the past about permissions. That's why i usually make it run using gksu (so that the whole application has root privileges). So it doesn't save  after you click that option. What happens when you click the preview? Does it suggest an alternative configuration? Compared to the current configuration?

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure it _does_ save, but then again, I don't know what the heck happens after that :( I mean, as you can see by my xorg.conf log above, the resolution *is* set... however, for some reason, the NVIDIA driver just isn't loading it.

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Anyone at all ?

Comment: Are you sure that the file before and the file after (the /etc/X11/xorg.conf) are different or are the exactly the same? Did you really launch it with "gksu" like I specified?

Comment: I've launched it with everything conceivable. And I'm pretty sure it changed. It's what's in the file after the fact that matters, right?

Comment: Yes. But it has this nice preview button. This way we can look whether the tool is correctly saving the wrong data, or badly tries to save the right data!